# Select next row based on current row field within one query

Tags: mysql

Let's say the table contains a list of waypoints.

```
 id | nextID
----+--------
  1 |      2 
  2 |      4
  3 |      5
  4 |      1
  5 |      0
```

Based on this table we have two pathes

- Circular (1 - 2 - 4 - 1)
- Linear (3 - 5)

How do I query the table to get these results:

```
      When starting ID = 1
 id | nextID
----+--------
  1 |      2 
  2 |      4
  4 |      1

      When starting ID = 3
 id | nextID
----+--------
  3 |      5
  5 |      0
```

Comment: So keep looping until you reach either a value that already exists in the result or 0?

Comment: @Strawberry I assume your comment bases on idea that I first obtain all the rows from the table, but I am not. I am curious about performing single `SELECT` query to get these results.

Comment: You can't. The circular part is procedural

Comment: @Strawberry what about linear one? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes - although (amongst the kind of people who write sprocs) it's quite common to write a sproc for that too. The pure MySQL solution isn't much fun, but I'll show you one option...

Answer (score 1):

For the linear problem, you can do this. Note that I've used NULL instead of 0 for orphans...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT PRIMARY KEY
,nextID INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,2),
(2,4),
(3,5),
(4,1),
(5,NULL);

SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',a.id,b.id,c.id) path 
  FROM my_table a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table b 
    ON b.nextID = a.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table c 
    ON c.nextID = b.id 
 WHERE a.nextID IS NULL;
+------+
| path |
+------+
| 5,3  |
+------+
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution limits concat to 3 items only. However an interesting workaround!

Comment: More LEFT JOINs = more items. I think you're beginning to see the limitations of this model.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is called [***hierarchical query***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL).

> A hierarchical query is operated on **Hierarchical Data** where
>   parent-child relationship is stored in the same table.

**Oracle**, **DB2**, **Postgres** have special [syntaxes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) to query on hierarchical data.

In **Oracle** if you want to find the all possible path from a start point you have to use `START WITH CONNECT BY` query.

**Query**

```
SELECT id "start_point", CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE "Cycle",
  LEVEL, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(id, '/') "Path"
FROM waypoints START WITH id = 1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR next_id = id AND LEVEL <= 4;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**MySQL 8** will support this feature in [future](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html). But you can implement your own by following this [blog post](https://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/).

Hope this helps you. Ping me if you need further clarifications.